Moving files from a phone to an Ubuntu computer has a problem
I am having trouble with "other locations" on Ubuntu 24.04. It used to work, but now I have obviously done something or something has happened that has stopped it from working.
The problem is with using a Samsung phone and the app "Software data cable" to transfer files from the phone to the computer. I start this program on the phone and it behaves as usual, displaying: ftp://192.168.1.50:888
Connect PC to wifi FLX_GROUP and tap lower left button ...
FLX_GROUP is on my router and a second computer can access the internet through wifi using this connection, so it must be working.
Normally I would then go to the computer, nautilus/"other locations" and would be able to access ftp://192.168.1.50:8888 and all would be well, but now "other locations" only shows (after about 2 seconds) a network with my computer's host name, and then if I select that it display printer related data. The wifi printer is working.

use sftp command dear!!

I don't know the "Software data cable" program you're mentioning, but from your description I understand it's supposed to run a FTP server on the phone and you access that FTP server from a PC?
Despite the fact that the FTP server is not showing up in Nautilus, did you try to access it manually, just by typing the URL you mentioned ( ftp:// 192.168.1.50:8888 ) into Nautilus address bar?
